# Access elements of Join Tables in spring through Service

Tags: java, spring, many-to-many, join

I am trying to learn it and I am facing some conceptual issues.

Let's imagine to have the entities of Employee, Project and Department where:

```
Employee - Department is a ManyToOne relationship
Employee - Project is a ManyToMany relationship
```

Right now I have written this:

Employee.java
@Entity

```
public class Employee {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
    private String department;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="project_employee",
                joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
                inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private ArrayList<Project> projects;

//constructors, getters, setters...
}
```

Project.java

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String client;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="project")
    private ArrayList<Employee> employees;

//constructors, getters, setters...
    }
```

Department.java

```
@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private ArrayList<Employee> employees;

    //constructors, getters, setters...
        }
```

EmployeeService.java

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRep;
    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRep;
    @Autowired
    private DepartmentRepository deptRep;

    public List<Project> getProjectsByEmployee(Long emplId){

    }

}
```

The first solution that came in my mind to implement that methods was:

- Get the specific employee object through the `employeeRep` and then loop over its list project retrieving ids and using them to retrieve project info with `projectRep`.

But in this case it seems I am not exploiting the table relation I have between `Project` and `Employee`, so what's the point on having it then?

Comment: "super spring dumb here."  It looks like a new spring library !

Comment: cautionary tale :)

Comment: A side note : that mapping `@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
    private String department;` would be more JPA friendly if you replaced `String` by `Department`

Comment: you're totally right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in that case it seems to me that I am not exploiting the table
>   relation I have between Project and Employee, so what's the point on
>   having it then?

In fact you exploit that ManyToMany table when you access to the `Project` relationship from an `Employee` entity (JPA performs a query for you at that time) but you don't exploit it efficiently.  I will explain.

> The first solution that came in my mind to implement that methods was:
>
> Get the specific employee object through the employeeRep and then loop
>   over its list project retrieving ids and using them to retrieve
>   project info with projectRep.

That is bad idea because you don't want to perform a lot of queries while a single one rather simple could achieve the same thing.
Similarly defining a repository by entity is not mandatory :

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeeRep;
@Autowired
private ProjectRepository projectRep;
@Autowired
private DepartmentRepository deptRep;
```

if according to your requirements, your queries rely on a pivot table (for example the employee table), just declare :

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeeRep;
```

And perform the join from employee to project to get the list of projects for a specific employee.

In JPQL you could use fetch join on `projects` to get `projects` associated to the matching `employee` such as :

```
public List<Project> getProjectsByEmployee(Long empId){
    String jpql = "SELECT emp FROM Employee e" +
                  "INNER JOIN FETCH e.projects" +
                  "WHERE emp.id=:empId";
    TypedQuery<Employee> query = em.createQuery(jpql, Employee.class)
                                         .setParameter("empId", empId);
    Employee emp = query.getSingleResult();
    return emp.getProjects();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you clarify how the join can be performed?

Comment: You are welcome. Not tested but I can write something that should be close of the target. I update.